# Args to be optional when an option is used, else required

Tags: python, python-click

```
@cli.command()
@click.option("--list", 'list_steps', default=False, is_flag=True)
@click.argument("elem")
@click.pass_obj
def step(cmd, elem, list_steps):
    print(elem)
    print(list_steps)

    click.secho(elem, fg="blue", bold=True)
```

I am getting `Error: Missing argument 'ELEM'.` if i do `mycli step --list`.

Is it possible to not require an arg only if the option `--list` is used, otherwise require it?

Comment: Maybe make `elem` and `--list` mutually exclusive, and give `--list` an optional argument?

Comment: @Brian61354270 would it be possible for you to share an example code. i dont know how to make those two mutually exclusive nor give --list an optional arg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use the `click` module in python, but considering you are trying to develop a CLI interface, I would suggest you using argpase since it has way extensive syntax and broad scale of features.

```py
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example script with conditional arguments")

    parser.add_argument("-o", "--optional", action="store_true", help="Make argument -a optional")
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--arg", required=False, help="An argument that can be optional")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.optional and args.arg is None:
        print("Option -o used, argument -a is optional.")
    elif not args.optional and args.arg is None:
        parser.error("Argument -a is required when option -o is not used.")

    print("Program execution completed.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you but not planning on converting to use argparse